# How to move a solution file in TFS to a branch?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have the following structure in TFS,

```
 1.2.3.4\MyTFSProject
    Project1  
    Project2
       Dev
         Base
         Feature1
         Feature2
         Feature3
       Main
       Error
```

I accidentally checked in my 'Error' project in Project2. I wanted it to be a part of 'Dev' branch. How to move the project 'Error' to Dev (just like Base, Feature1, Feature2 are a part of Project2).

Comment: Open up the history browser, find the folder and right-click, do you have a Move menu item there?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly move the project in **Source Control Explorer**

1. Right click you project and select **move**.
   [image]
2. Select the right destination,Dev branch.
   [image]
3. You will get a rename status pending change, just **check in the pending changes.**
   [image]